# Xamarin Forms variable initialization

Tags: .net, variables, xamarin, xamarin.forms, initialization

I just started working with Xamarin Forms, but there is smth strange, that I cannot understand
I want to use CarouselView control and setting as a ItemsSource a list of names

I was getting the error index out of bounds every time I deploy it to my phone, when I debugged it - I saw that list of names never initialized, despite I clearly doing it.

This is probably some rookie mistake, but please help me with it.

[image]

Application uses .NET standart 2.0, deploying to Meizu m3 note (Android 5.1)

XAML file:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="GMS.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GMS">


    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            Margin="20"
            FontSize="50"
            Text="CarouselView"
            TextColor="Black" />

        <forms:CarouselView x:Name="CarouselView">
            <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label FontSize="60" Text="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </forms:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

Same thing when I try to do that in OnAppearing():
[image]

And when I put the code after initialization:
[image]

Comment: You should assign ItemSource after InitializeComponent();

Comment: @nirmalsubedi I tried that as well, same result

Comment: Can you post your XAML as well.

Comment: try doing this in OnAppearing, not the constructor

Comment: Its fine if he does that inside Constructor but he should do after InitializeComponent(); But its not recommended to do that in constructor though.

Comment: @nirmalsubedi added xaml code

Comment: @jason same thing when I override OnAppearing() method

Comment: I tried and exact same code of yours works!!! Did you tried clearing your Project, Delete Bin/Obj folder then Restart the Visual studio. Sometime it works that way. Because I copy pasted your code and it is working fine.

Comment: Im unable to run android 5.1 but exact same works on newer android version. I tested using android 8.1. So see if you can run same in newer version.

Comment: @nirmalsubedi cleared the solution, deleted bin/obj folders manually from both main and android projects, didn't help
I'll create simulator with android 8.1 and will test it on it later

Comment: @nirmalsubedi thank you
when I run emulator it worked
it was older version of android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @NirmalSubedi for answering
The reason of this was Android 5.1 that my phone have, and when I run this on emulator Android 8.1 - it was fine